# How to identify the hosts in my playbook from a variable file?

Tags: ansible-inventory

on my hosts file, I have like 10 different groups that each has devices in it. each customer deployment, should go to a specific region and I want to specify that in a customer config file.

In my playbook, I tried to use a variable in front of hosts and my plan was to specify the hosts group in the config file.

### master_playbook.yml

hosts: "{{ target_region }}"

vars:

custom_config_file: "./app_deployment/customer_config_files/xx_app_prod.yml"

### xx_app_prod.yml

customer: test1

env: prod

app_port: 25073

target_region: dev

### Error message I get:

ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'target_region' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

To determine a HOST(who is not the running host) in which groups he is in u have to use a little helper:
Create a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook
#call like:  ./showgroups -i develop -l jessie.fritz.box
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: show the groups the host(s) are in
    debug:
      msg: "{{group_names}}"
```

After that u can run a Playbook Like:

```
- name: "get group memberships of host"
  shell: "{{ role_path }}/files/scripts/show_groups -i {{ fullinventorypath }} -l {{ hostname }}"
  register: groups

- name: "create empty list of group memberships"
  set_fact:
    memberships: []
- name: "fill list"
  set_fact:
    memberships: "{{ memberships + item }}"
  with_items:  groups.stdout.lines
```